# Is it possible to get values before elements exist in the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got some tabs on a site, and when a tab is clicked I'd like to hide a Load more button if that tab does not contain any data. 
To do this I wanted to check the value being returned before it actually exists in the DOM. 
My code looks something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#tabs li').click(function(event){
var id = 1;
var tab_id = 2;        

$(".l").load("show.php?id="+id, {"tab_id": tab_id});

var load = ($("show.php?id="+id, {"tab_id": tab_id})).val();


alert(load);


});


})
```

The idea being that if variable load is not null the show the Load more button, if it is null then hide the load button. I'm sure I'm not taking the best approach, any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: `$("show.php?id="+id, {"tab_id": tab_id})` is this an AJAX call? What on earth is this?

Comment: You can load some content into a javascript variable, modify it and then insert it in the DOM.  You can't use `.load()` for that, though, you'd probably use `$.get()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use $.get():

```
$.get('show.php?id'+id, {
    "tab_id": tab_id
}, function(data) {
    //data contains the data from your show.php page.
    if(data.length > 0) {
        //there is data show so load button
    } else {
        //Hide load button
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the success callback of load

```
$(".l").load("show.php?id="+id, {"tab_id": tab_id}, function(serverResponse){
   if( !serverResponse ){
      /* do something when no response */
   }
});
```

See: [**load() API Docs**](http://api.jquery.com/load/)